# Show the GUI button when mouse hover to the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i already have this player on my screen. And i want, whenever the mouse hover at the object, the GUI button show itself (like tooltip). I tried below code, but the button is not showed up when i hover at the object. Here is my code:

```
void OnMouseEnter()

    {

        Rect buttonRect = new Rect(250, Screen.height - buttonHeight, textInfoPlayerButtonWidth, textInfoPlayerButtonHeight);



        if (GameManager.instance.currentPlayerIndex == 0) (the object)

        {

            if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "This is player 1"))

            {



            }

        }

    }
```

I want to be it like this:
[image]

But i want it to be show that GUI hovering button on that character, not when the character selected.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug the problem? Where are your debug console logs? Where is the code attached? We need a lot more information.

Comment: i tried the below solutions, but none of them are working @S.Richmond. I tried many ways but also the GUI won't showed up when i hovering mouse to my object. the code attached in the Player class. I access the movement and the attack on that class

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the *MouseHover* event instead. *MouseEnter* would be called **as soon** as the mouse is over the given object. *MouseHover* on the other hand is only triggered when the mouse remains over the given object for X amount of time (although I'm not sure exactly how long this takes).

(Also, I'm not sure if you had correctly set-up the your event handler as a subscriber of the *MouseEnter* event in your example, but here's a link explaining it : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/awbftdfh.aspx)

You can then show your Rect object :

```
Component myComponent.MouseHover += new EventHandler(OnMouseHover);

...

void OnMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rect buttonRect = new Rect(250, Screen.height - buttonHeight, textInfoPlayerButtonWidth, textInfoPlayerButtonHeight);

    if (GameManager.instance.currentPlayerIndex == 0) (the object)
    {
        if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "This is player 1"))
        {
            //accomplish whatever you had wanted here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `MouseHover` is based on some system properties: [SystemInformation.MouseHoverSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousehoversize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.mousehovertime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this is correct for Unity3D? I think you're assuming OP is using the .NET GUI framework?

Answer (score 0):

if the object is a 3d object, then the only way I know of to find out if the mouse is hovering above that object is with raycasting. Here's a quick example:

```
void Update() 
{
    Ray ray = Camera.mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject == playerObject)
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

OR

```
void Update() 
{
    Ray ray = Camera.mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject.name == "myPlayerObjectName")
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

This however is probably going to be very cpu intensive as is, so you may want to run it on a timer or something, eg once every 5 seconds, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you sir, but i already tried your code and it is not working to me

Comment: hmm... The only reason I can think of for the raycast to fail is if the player Object either doesn't have a collider, or there's another object with a collider between the camera and the player object. Or if the object is on the GUI instead of being a 3d game object. Have you checked to see what the raycast is hitting?

Comment: I copied your code and on the part "Do something here", i make "Debug.Log("Testing");" and when i run the program and mouse cursor on the object, the Debug Log is not showed up

Comment: Where I've put `playerObject` you need to put the instance of your player object in the current scene. If you don't know how to do that, try the second method I editted into my answer, which searches by name.

Comment: it is cannot also sir, it seems like the code is not working at all.